# npm/yarn module install with git: cloning repo into node_modules and installing does not work but yarn add does

Tags: node.js, git, react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I'm trying to make a contribution to an opensource project. In particular, react-native.

I have a test app which I've created with `create-react-native-app test` if I do the following:

```
cd test
rm -rf node_modules/react-native
yarn add https://github.com/<mygithub>/react-native # (my fork)
```

There's no issue when I start my app with `yarn run ios`

However, if I try to clone my fork into node_modules and install it manually with the following:

```
cd test
rm -rf node_modules/react-native
git clone https://github.com/<mygithub>/react-native
cd react-native
yarn install
```

I get all sorts of issues. Namely, in my case:

```
console.error: "React Native version mismatch. 
JavaScript version: 0.0.0
Native version: 0.52.0
...
```

Which to me indicates that something in cloning and manually installing is done differently than adding the package with `yarn install` and a github url.

I want to be able to work out of a git repo to commit my work and if I use yarn install it is not an initialized git repo. For lack of a better solution, how can I get manually cloning and installing a node_module with yarn to yield the same result as adding it with yarn install?

Edit to add steps attempted for yarn-link:

```
git clone https://github.com/<mygithub>/react-native
cd react-native
yarn install
yarn link
cd ../test
yarn link "react-native"
```

This results in the same results as cloning my fork into test/node_modules.

Edit 2: I should add, according the the react-native docs, I should be able to install my fork by cloning it into my project's node_modules folder and installing. The only difference is that I'm using yarn. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html#building-the-source

Comment: Sounds like you want `git clone https://github.com/<mygithub>/react-native` and then `yarn link ./react-native` in a test project that depends on your fork.

Comment: You would think! That was actually my first attempt. I tried it again just to be sure but it yeilds the same result as cloning into node_modules. I abandoned the yarn link approach because I thought expo may not be following symlinks but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by cloning _into_ node modules. If you are working on a package, it should not be in that folder.

Comment: I agree, sorry. Cloning my repo into test/node_modules was a second effort when yarn link failed. Since yarn link creates a symlink, correct me if I'm wrong, I reasoned that the react-native packager might not be following symlinks. When either approach produced the same results (cloning into node_modules vs yarn link) I figured it didn't matter either way. Does that make sense?

Comment: React-native packager sounds interesting. Sounds like your requirement is actually something different. You probably want to operate on the react-native checkout while directly using the result in the consuming project, right? Please add such details to your question. Please also add the steps you did using `yarn link`. Please read the [yarn link docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/) carefully a second time and try it again.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the response. I added my yarn link commands and tripple checked I was using them as per the docs here: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/

Comment: These bugs seem to be related to the "link problem": https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/637 (there seems to be one unmerged fix in a fork) and https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1

Comment: Thanks again for the effort. I found those issues too and came to the conclusion that getting linking to work would be a huge headache. Do you know if cloning my fork of react-native into my project's node_modules (/test/node_modules) _should_ indeed work? My understanding is that it should.